# Display start and end date range in timeseries LineChart using HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a simple line chart where I am trying to display time series data which have start and end. Like this

```
{"beginTimeSeconds": 1626145840, "endTimeSeconds": 1626232240, "totalTimeInSeconds": 0, "uri": "/logout"}
```

However, as per HighChart config timeseries only accept one timestamp like this.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'test'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Test',
        data: [
            [1167609600000, 0.7537], // Only one timestamp
            [1167696040000, 0.7537] // Only one timestamp
        ]
    }]
});
```

Is there any way to pass range so that tooltip shows Start date - end date followed by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by default in Highcharts, your point contains 4 main attributes which you can specify. Its x and y value, its name, and color. API reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

If you'd like your point to have some more attributes you can add them and e.g use one of them in the tooltip. Something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k49z8mv0/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
  zoomType: 'x'
 },
 xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime'
 },
 yAxis: {
  title: {
   text: 'test'
  }
 },
 legend: {
  enabled: false
 },
 tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
   return 'Point value is: ' + this.y + '<br/>The total time in Second 
    equals: ' + this.point.totalTimeInSeconds + '<br/>' + 
    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.point.beginTimeSeconds) + ' - 
    ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.point.endTimeSeconds);
  }
},
series: [{
type: 'line',
name: 'Test',
data: [{
    x: 1167609600000,
    y: 0.7537,
    beginTimeSeconds: 1626145840,
    endTimeSeconds: 1626232240,
    totalTimeInSeconds: 0
  },
  {
    x: 1167696040000,
    y: 0.7537,
    beginTimeSeconds: 1626145840,
    endTimeSeconds: 1626232240,
    totalTimeInSeconds: 1
  }
]
}]
});
```

If that doesn't answer your question please precise what the issue is.

Comment: Yeah that was it. I found the solution yesterday and was about to post solution but you beat me :) thanks